# Weird behavior in for for loop in windows 10

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, windows-10, echo

I have a simple script (It works fine on windows server)
Running it on windows 10 it gives one extra result.
The script basically does the following.
It finds all files with a .pak extension and makes sure they have a .bod file also.
So for example file1.pak should have a file1.bod

When i run the script

```
echo off
for /f %%f in ('dir /b /s /a:-d *.pak') do (
if not exist %%~dpnf.bod echo "%%~dpnf.pak has no bod"
)
```

I get the following in windows10 but i would expect no result

```
C:\temp\pakbodtest>echo off
"C:\temp\pakbodtest>echo.pak has no bod"
```

This line here is unexpected
Does anyone know how to resolve?

```
"C:\temp\pakbodtest>echo.pak has no bod"
```

Comment: can't replicate (working fine here). (besides you could simplify to `echo "%%~ff has no bod"` and you should use `delims=` to be able to process file names with spaces)

Comment: I would change it to, `@For /F %%A In ('Dir /B/S/A-D *.pak 2^>Nul') Do @If Not Exist "%%~dpnA.bod" Echo "%%~dpnA.pak has no bod"`

Comment: Personally I would use a `FOR /R` in this scenario. `FOR /R %%G in (*.pak) do IF NOT EXIST "%%~G.bod" echo "%%G" has no bod`

Comment: Do you get that every time? What files do you have in your dir? Maybe a *symlink* is playing tricks on you?

Comment: @stephan 2^>Nul seemed to work here for me

Comment: @CristiFati No symlinks in play. As i said for some reason the 2^nul seems to work

Answer (score 0):

Thanks folks @stephan was right with the 2^>Nul
Thanks for the comments

Comment: actually, it was @Compo, who suggested `2>nul`